# Difference in Renderer2 and DOCUMENT token for DOM manipulation

Tags: angular

I have come across the DOCUMENT token which can be injected to manipulate DOM.

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
}
```

However, we can also manipulate the DOM using Renderer2 as follows:

```
import { Renderer2, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent2 {
    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {}
}
```

So my question is what is the recommended way and what is the difference between the above two approaches?

Comment: Prefer renderer2 since that’s how angular renders the template e.g. to add encapsulation. Document “bypasses” angular’s rendering model

Comment: What do you mean by rendering model, could you give some references?

Comment: Basically angular takes the template and steps through the nodes (native html, custom components, ng-template's etc) and uses the [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to convert to html. The easiest way I've seen to get a deeper understanding is to provide a custom renderer which implement and just calls all the underlying Renderer2 apis but adds a console.log beforehand. But the renderer is provided *at the component level* and pulls in the view encapsulation (hence why you can change this per component).